# Python. How to draw some points into a image

Tags: python

I want to draw some points with a given size and color in a regular image file using python but I can't find the right modules for do this. For example:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('.../file.jpg/')
xcoordinate = [10, 20, 30, 40]
ycoordinate = [20, 30, 50, 60]
sizePoint = 5

## Can't find this
drawPoints(im, (xcoordinate, ycoordnate), size = sizePoint, color = 'red') 

cv2.imshow('Example',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any advice would be great thanks

Comment: why not `cv2.circle(im, (x, y), radius, color)` with a small radius? also, if you specify thickness with a negative value it will draw a filled circle

Comment: @fedterzi thanks for the advice,